# Black screen with PHPGraphlib PHP charts demo

Tags: php, mysql, phpgraphlib

I am trying to implement the PHP Graph demo (http://www.ebrueggeman.com/phpgraphlib/documentation/tutorial-mysql-and-phpgraphlib) for php chart given in this tutorial. But on adding the second line of the demo, it is giving a black screen. These are the first two lines of demo

```
include("phpgraphlib.php");
$graph=new PHPGraphLib(550,350);
```

I checked servers PHP version and GD version. They are in order What could be the reason for the black screen and how to implement the php graph. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just answering for reference sake..

```
include("phpgraphlib.php");
$graph = new PHPGraphLib(400,300);
$data = array("Alex"=>99, "Mary"=>98, "Joan"=>70, "Ed"=>90);
$graph->addData($data);
$graph->setTitle("Test Scores");
$graph->setTextColor("blue");
$graph->createGraph();
```